# Is it possible to run PHP exec() but hide params from the process list?

Tags: php, mysql, shell

I'd like to have a properly protected PHP web-based tool to run a `mysqlcheck` for general database table health, but I don't want the password to be visible in the process list. I'd like to run something like this:

```
$output = shell_exec('mysqlcheck -Ac -uroot -pxxxxx -hhostname');

// strip lines that's OK
echo '<pre>'.preg_replace('/^.+\\sOK$\\n?/m', '', $output).'</pre>';
```

Unfortunately, with a `shell_exec()`, I have to include the password in the command line, but am concerned that the password will show up in the process list (`ps -A | grep mysqlcheck`).

Using mariadb 5.5 on my test machine, mysqlcheck doesn't show the password in the process list, but my production machine isn't running mariadb and running a different OS and I'd like to be on the safe-side and not run these tests on the production side.

Do all versions of mysql also hide the password in the process list? Are my concerns a non-issue?

Comment: what if you create a bash script and run mysql from it; then call che bash script from exec?

Comment: It's up to the app you're exec'ing to rewrite the process list to remove sensitive stuff like passwords, and even then there's a bit of a race condition where the pw would STILL be available until such time as the sub-process can get to the rewriting phase.

Comment: According to the manual: `mysqlcheck uses the SQL statements CHECK TABLE, REPAIR TABLE, ANALYZE TABLE, and OPTIMIZE TABLE in a convenient way for the user.`. So you could write your own version in a php script using just PDO or mysqli and no `shell_exec`.

Comment: There are multiple ways, however in this case with mysql you can more easily do it by specifying a [`--defaults-file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-file)

Comment: @jeroen a looping php script was my backup plan, but with using the included binary to do exactly that seems like a better choice if it was feasible. Thanks for the details on mysqlcheck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since at least MySQL 5.1, the client obscures the password on the command-line.

I found this blog by former MySQL Community Manager Lenz Grimmer from 2009, in which he linked to the relevant code in the MySQL 5.1 source.  http://www.lenzg.net/archives/256-Basic-MySQL-Security-Providing-passwords-on-the-command-line.html

You could alternatively *not* pass the password on the command-line at all, and instead store the user/password credentials in a file which PHP has privileges to read, and then execute the client as:

```
mysqlcheck --defaults-extra-file=/etc/php.d/mysql-client.cnf
```

The filename is an example; you can specify any path you want.  The point is that most MySQL client tools accept that `--defaults-extra-file` option.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-file-options.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It is a real concern and your OS will be showing it, Just not maybe in the default view.

You could [proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) instead which will allow you to read and write to the stream opened by that file.

```
mysqlcheck -Ac -uroot -p -hhostname
```

will prompt for the password which you can write to with the pipes from proc_open